# How do I algerbraically prove that the equation $2^x = \frac{10}{x}$ has no solution for $x < 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

I am not sure about my approach here:

**Write both sides of the equation as separate function:**

$f(x)=2^x$

and

$h(x)=\frac{10}{x}$

**Take the limit of $f(x)$**

$\lim_{x \to -∞} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -∞}2^x$

$\lim_{x \to -∞}2^x = 0$

**Take the limit of $h(x)$**

$\lim_{x \to -∞} h(x) = \lim_{x \to -∞}\frac{10}{x}$

$\lim_{x \to -∞}\frac{10}{x} = 0$

The limits both equal $0$. This doesn't seem satisfactory as both limits equal the same number.  Am I even on the right track here?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you really mean that? One is positive and the other is negative for $x<0$.

Comment: You've only show that both sides go to 0 as x goes to −∞. What you need to also say is that $2^x$ is always positive and 10/x is always negative for x<0, so the will never meet.

Comment: Okay that makes sense to me now. Thank you.

Comment: If you get log both sides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One side is always positive, the other always negative. Thus they cannot be equal.

Limits isn't the way to go to exclude the existence of solutions. Functions can have the same limit and never be equal, and they can be equal many times yet still have different limits.

If the limits are different, then using concrete $\varepsilon$ and $N$ from the proofs of those limits can help you rule out the existence of solutions far away from $0$, and it can even tell you exactly how far away you have to go for this guarantee to hold. If the limits are the same, however, then limit considerations are not likely to help.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot have $10=x2^{x}$ for  $x <0$ because $x2^{x} <0$.

Comment: Was my approach okay?

Comment: No your approach is not good.

Comment: @HoratioNelson It's unclear how the limit would help you, even if the two limits were different

Answer (score 1):

$2^x$ and $\frac{10}{x}$ are elementary functions (an exponential whose graphic is rather similar to $e^x$ and a hyperbola which is like $\frac{1}{x}$ times a constant). You can easily plot them by hand. What you find is the following:

[image]

You can check that for $x < 0$ the two curves do not intersect. The only solution is in the positive part of the plane, that is for $x > 0$.

In this way you can also see that a real solution exists and it's also unique.